# Can a MySQL user have limiter delete, update permissions?

Tags: mysql, privileges, sql-grant

For a user in MySQL 5.6, can I limit the privileges to the point where the user can have delete, update privileges but

- The user cannot update the whole table (no update without a where clause)
- The user cannot delete the whole table (no delete without a where clause)

Comment: Impossible, `where 1=1 ` is correct `where`

Comment: @AlexMuravyov - No other workarounds?

Comment: May be this help - https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/grant/#column-privileges

Comment: Disable direct update and delete on table for user and use stored functions